# Unable to deploy Cosmos DB Service - Australia Central

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-cosmosdb

I have been trying to deploy an instance of Azure Cosmos DB but receive this error during the deployment.

**EDIT:** I receive the same error when trying to deploy to US and East Asia.

{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"Conflict","message":"{\r\n \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n \"error\": {\r\n \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n \"details\": [\r\n {\r\n \"code\": \"ServiceUnavailable\",\r\n \"message\": \"Sorry, we are currently experiencing high demand in this region, and cannot fulfill your request at this time. We work continuously to bring more and more capacity online, and encourage you to try again shortly. Please do not hesitate to contact us via Azure support at any time or for any reason using this link [http://aka.ms/azuresupport.\r\nActivityId](http://aka.ms/azuresupport.%5Cr%5CnActivityId): 3a4fdf27-f7cd-4bc1-bc98-b752cafd7a78, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0\"\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n}"}]}

Is this purely related to the increase in cloud users over the past month due to COVID19? Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61120805/cosmos-db-deployment-failures

Comment: Does this answer your question? [COSMOS DB Deployment failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61120805/cosmos-db-deployment-failures)

Comment: Maybe such question could be submitted to cosmos db team directly to verify the truth.