# COSMOS DB Deployment failures

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have been struggling to create a COSMOS DB since a couple of days...I am getting this below error which doesnt make any sense to me. What does this error mean and what to do?

{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"Conflict","message":"{\r\n \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n \"error\": {\r\n \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n \"details\": [\r\n {\r\n \"code\": \"ServiceUnavailable\",\r\n \"message\": \"Sorry, we are currently experiencing high demand in this region, and cannot fulfill your request at this time. We work continuously to bring more and more capacity online, and encourage you to try again shortly. Please do not hesitate to contact us via Azure support at any time or for any reason using this link [http://aka.ms/azuresupport.\r\nActivityId](http://aka.ms/azuresupport.%5Cr%5CnActivityId): , Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0\"\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n}"}]}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening due to the current COVID situation. Please check the announcement from MS Team regarding this:

https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/our-commitment-to-customers-and-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/

It also provides links to other articles to follow in this issue.

Please use the Azure Portal to raise your request. Please follow instructions here to request access to a region. The access will be checked from case to case and access to locations given.

MS is committed to help every one but all of us are in the situation which has never occurred before and we continue to monitor the situation and will keep you updated.

Comment: Hello,  Thank you!!

I have found out that emulator can be used for the development purposes. That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is not capacity in the region you're attempting to provision Cosmos DB in at this time. Your options are to wait until capacity becomes available, or provision in a different region.

Comment: I tried all US regions but same error everywhere. Thank you!!